Почему не работает transition? Firefox
.carousel-item button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1vw;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: var(--white-main);
    border: .1vw solid var(--gray-dull);
    border-left: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0%;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.carousel-item button:hover {
    color: var(--gray-main);
}

На движке Хрома transition работает (тестил в Vivaldi), а на Фаерфоксовском нет (тестил в Waterfox).
При этом на других элементах всё ок, а именно на кнопке не пашет, памагити

Раз только на кнопке не пашет, значит какой-то встроенный стиль сбивает. Возможно Bootstrap или ещё какой-то прежде настроенный на кнопку, бывает же делают заготовки кнопок и прочего, что бы легче было верстать.
